# Retrieve data from a table with a condition where and check the record in another table in one SELECT query

Tags: php, mysql

Need in one query query retrieve data from one table with condition "where" simultaneously check if another table exists ip user, then display results in while display information whether there exists ip

tables:

```
Ips (
   Id int (10) not null auto_increment,
   User_id int (10) not null default '0',
   Ip varchar (40) not null
)

Users (
   Id int (11) not null auto_increment,
   Username varchar (35) not null,
   Email varchar (200) not null,
   Salt varchar (40) not null,
   Password varchar (40) not null,
   Country varchar (40) not null
)
```

What I want to get:

1. Get data from the users table with the condition "where country = 'paris' LIMIT 0.10"
2. Each time you check that the ips table exists with a user id and ip address with $ _SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR']
3. If there is a record in the table ips display the information in while

My current problem code:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$db = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN ips ON ips.user_id=users.id ON ips.ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' WHERE users.country='paris' LIMIT 0,10");

if (mysqli_num_rows($db)>0){
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)){
        print_r($data);
        if (filter_var($data['ip'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){ //check var is ip adress
            echo '<br>isset ip';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'not records';
}

?>
```

Ps: I could not find an answer in the proposals

Comment: can you post the initial code that u did

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We try to fix your code, we do not write your code___

Comment: Its called a JOIN! Look it up in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) or look for [a tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/joins.php)

Comment: from your code: `... JOIN ips ON ips.user_id=users.id ON ips.ip= ...` 1 on only! `ON` should connect tables, filtering conditions go into `WHERE` clause. ``FROM `Users` `u` INNER JOIN `Ips` `i` ON `u`.`id` = `i`.`User_id` WHERE ... AND ...  ORDER BY `u`.`Id`;`` Joined tables are the best way since joins have a better performance than subqueries. Btw.: Do not insert any client data into your SQL string. Use prepared statements with bound parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Country ='paris' AND Id IN (SELECT User_id  FROM Ips  WHERE Ip = 'ip_adddress')
```

Comment: Your example works if the name and ip are given.

I made the code:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '% NAME%' AND ID IN (SELECT user_id FROM Ips WHERE Ip = 'IP ADRESS')

Need to search for users like in a regular query:
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '% NAME%'

In addition, check the ips tables to see if there is a record that contains the specified
Ip address along with the user id of the line. If there is such a record, the message will be displayed and the results returned as normal. I wrote everything in the picture: http://iv.pl/images/11692056913053727462.png